# Parse error , Wordpress No FTP server

Tags: wordpress, syntax-error

I edited function.php file in wordpress. I edited this accidenlty incorrect. When i try to login in or go on wordpress page there is an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''" data-text="'' (...) "
I dont have installed plugin with ftp on wordpress, what is the solution ?how to fix it?

Comment: Are you saying that you broke your WordPress site when making a change to your functions.php file? Do you have a backup? Post the code around the lines that give you the error.

Comment: First, please post code here, along with the complete error message. You haven't posted enough for us even to guess what the error is. Second, what does FTP have to do with this? FTP access is not a plugin functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I know where error is, I just dont have access to fix it. I cant even log in to wp-admin.

Here is whole error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''" data-text="'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home3/dhazard/public_html/zero-below.com/wp-content/themes/credenza-wp/vc_templates/thb_share.php on line 10

I dont have code because i dont have access to this.

I tried to access via ftp but it doesn't work.
Is there any other way to access wordpress files to fix this bug in code?